# How to wrap word in single colon and separate words with comma using javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have around 100 word in following format
abc
def
eft
fgg
asd
and so on....till n numbers

I want it to be like 'abc','def','eft' and so on...

Basically i am trying to insert a row in database.

I am really confused. Can you guys help me out with logic. I have huge list cant do manually.

Comment: Why JavaScript then? Are you trying to do this in Node?

Comment: And what did you try already? You have to provide some code as a starting point.

Comment: i am looking for automated way to do it. all I am looking for is some guidance on how to achieve this and in which language or some tool.not specific to any language. @raina77ow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one of many ways to do it

```
var source = document.querySelector("pre").textContent;

var items = source.split("\n"); //Split items by new line
items = items.map(function(item) { //Trim whitespace off of each item
    return item.trim(); 
}).filter(function(item) { //Filter out empty items
    return item;
});

var list = "'" + items.join("','") + "'"; //Join items together by single quotes and comas, and add single quotes at the beggining and the end
alert(list);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m1n7xc6r/